# Evaluating $\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+1}{b^x+1}\,\mathrm dx$ for a $y$-axis symmetrical function $f$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $[-a, a] \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval. Let $f: [-a, a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann-integrable function such that $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x \in [-a, a]$. Let $b \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

**Question:** Is there a "good" way to simplify the integral $\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x) + 1}{b^x+1} \,\mathrm dx$?

Comment: Possibly helpful: [What functions $g$ satisfy $\int_{-L}^{L} \frac{f(x)}{1 + g(x)}\:dx = \int_{0}^{L} f(x)\:dx$ for every even function $f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3043550/42969).

Answer (score 8):

Yes! In fact,

> $$\displaystyle\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+1}{b^x+1} \,\mathrm dx= a+\int_0^a f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x.$$

*Proof.*
We have
\begin{equation}\label{*}\tag{*}
\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+1}{b^x+1} \,\mathrm dx \overset{\text{substituting } x \rightarrow -x}{=} (-1)^2 \cdot \int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+1}{b^{-x}+1} \,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-a}^a \frac{b^x \cdot (f(x) + 1)}{b^x + 1} \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Thus
\begin{split}
\displaystyle 2 \cdot \int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+1}{b^x+1} \,\mathrm{d}x &\overset{\eqref{*}}{=} \int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+1}{b^x+1} \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{-a}^a \frac{b^x \cdot (f(x)+1)}{b^x+1} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
 &= \int_{-a}^a \frac{(b^x+1) \cdot (f(x)+1)}{b^x+1} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{-a}^a f(x)+1 \,\mathrm{d}x = 2 a + \int_{-a}^a f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{split}

This achieves a proof. $\square$